# animejs float numbers

Tags: javascript, anime.js

Я пытаюсь анимировать заполнение числа от 0.00 до 100.00% с помощью anime.js

но когда число анимируется после запятой появляется слишком много символов
Так как ниже

```js
let text = document.querySelector('p')
let procent = parseFloat(text.dataset.procent) 

let anim = anime({
    loop: false,
    autoplay: false,
    targets: text,
    innerHTML: `${procent}%`,
    duration: 4000,
    easing: 'linear'
})
anim.play()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/3.2.0/anime.min.js"></script>

<p data-procent="75.23">0.00%</p>
```

Я хочу чтобы у меня было фиксировано 2 числа после запятой

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const text = document.querySelector('p');
let procent = parseFloat(text.dataset.procent);

const anim = anime({
  loop: false,
  autoplay: false,
  targets: text,
  textContent: procent,
  round: 100,             // ◄◄◄
  duration: 4000,
  easing: 'linear',
});
anim.play();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/3.2.0/anime.min.js"></script>

<p data-procent="75.23">0.00%</p>
```

Параметр `round` описан в [документации библиотеки](https://animejs.com/documentation/#round).

Comment: Хоть я и убрал строковую интерполяцию через шаблон для демонстрации "и так тоже работает", мне не совсем понятна логика поведения библиотеки в отношении символа `%` (то есть, неясно, почему сохраняется символ процента)... Если есть сомнения в стабильности такого поведения, то добавление этого символа лучше оставить (или вернув тот вариант что в вопросе, или в значении параметра написав `procent + '%'`).

Comment: Супер и правда!
Сколько смотрел в документации не видел в упор

Comment: @DiZeRTiR, так да, документация у либы оформлена красиво, но она не шибко-то удобная. Поиска/фильтра ей остро не хватает :) Конечно, Ctrl+F в ней работает, но при этом не происходит скролла к результату пока не покликать "вперед-назад" в браузерном диалоге поиска (как раз такими танцами с бубном я ответ нашел)...